# Cut a string at byte length: how to identify invalid utf-8 characters?

Tags: javascript, utf-8

I need to cut an input string at a certain byte length and discard the rest. Every good answer to such a request involves encoding the string, slicing the required portion, decoding the result and removing the "replacement character".

But I discovered an edge case where the character "✊" appears 3 bytes before the cut point.

Here's some code demonstrating it.

```
function cutString(str, b1, b2)
{
  const te = new TextEncoder("utf-8"),
    td = new TextDecoder("utf-8"),
    enc = te.encode(str),
    cut = enc.slice(b1, b2),
    res = td.decode(cut);
  console.log(res);
}

cutString("abc✊def", 0, 5)
> abc�

cutString("abc✊def", 0, 6)
> abc✊

cutString("abc✊def", 6)
> def
```

If I cut the string after the 5th byte, everything works. If I cut it after the 6th byte I get a valid, but incorrect, utf-8 output.

Here's the bits of the 2 "fist" characters.

```
function showBits(char)
{
  const te = new TextEncoder("utf-8"),
    enc = te.encode(char),
    arr = Array.from(enc),
    map = arr.map(i => i.toString(2))
  console.log(map.join(" "));
}

showBits("✊")
> 11100010 10011100 10001010 11110000 10011111 10001111 10111100

showBits("✊")
> 11100010 10011100 10001010
```

So if I find the following in the next 4 bytes after the cut point, I know that I need to remove the final character from the output:

`11110000 10011111 10001111 10111100`

But what if the fist appears 4 bytes before the cut point?

```
cutString("ab✊cdef", 0, 6)
> ab✊�
```

Then I need to remove the replacement character and check for the last 3 of those bytes above.

I don't know what possible byte combinations might appear after the cut point to indicate a split multi-byte character. I was hoping someone would be able to explain it and help me create a general solution.

Thanks.

Comment: There is an [Emoji Sequence](https://emojipedia.org/emoji-sequence/) in your string (truncated): - `c` (U+0063,  *Latin Small Letter C*)
- `✊` (U+270A,  *Raised Fist*)
- `` (U+1F3FC, *EMOJI MODIFIER FITZPATRICK TYPE-3 (0xd83c,0xdffc)*)
- `d` (U+0064,  *Latin Small Letter D*), see also https://emojipedia.org/emoji-modifier-sequence#grid

Comment: Thanks, Josef. That's not the only type of data that might follow the cut point though. For example, the byte sequence for the flag of the Ascension Islands () is f0 9f 87 a6 f0 9f 87 a8. The first and second sets of 4 bytes both accord with utf-8 encoding (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding), so if I cut that character at the 4th byte I don't know how to identify that an 8-byte character has been cut, unless I hard-code a huge lookup table in my application. Maybe I'll have to do that, I have no idea!

Comment: Don't use a lookup table. Get a real Unicode library instead.  If you slice off a combining or modifier codepoint, you likely need to slice off the preceding codepoint(s) that where being combined/modified.  You need something that will identify the characteristics of each codepoint that you slice off.  Don't try to code that manually.